# error: request for member 'push_back' in 'myVector', which is of non-class type 'std::vector<Base>*'?

Tags: c++

`Base` is my base class, which also has derived classes `derived1` and `derived2`. I want to use dynamic binding, making a vector of `Base` pointers which can `push_back()` any `Base`, `derived1` and `derived2` objects. However, it is telling me that the push_back() function isn't the correct type?

Code in `main()`:

```
vector<Base> *myVector;

myFunction(myVector);
```

Function:

```
void myFunction(vector<Base> *&myVector)
{
    Base *b = new Base;

    myVector.push_back(b);

    delete [] b;
}
```

Comment: well you defined your vector as of type `Base` not of type `Base*`! this line `vector<Base> *myVector;` defines a pointer to a vector of type `Base` not a vector of Base pointers

Comment: Also, you really don't want to delete the pointer immediately after you add it to the vector... (and even if you did, you'd use `delete` not `delete []`)

Comment: [read this please](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6101039/Modern%20C%2B%2B.pdf).

Comment: consider using some smart pointer (e.g. std::shared_ptr) to wrap b into. Will help you not to leak memory.. Or be sure to release everything from myVector when you're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use vector of pointers to Base:

```
vector<Base*>
```

Also don't use pointers to vectors, you can pass vector to your function through reference:

```
void myFunction(vector<Base*> &myVector)
{
    Base *b = new Base;

    myVector.push_back(b);
}
```

Don't `delete b;` at the end of `myFunction` as it will make your pushed pointer invalid.

Finally, what you would ultimately want is to use [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), so:

```
vector<unique_ptr<Base>> myVector;
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
vector<Base *> myVector;
```

your code

```
vector<Base> * myVector;
```

creates pointer to a vector of type `vector<Base>`, which is not what you want. What you want is vector of type `vector<Base *>`.

Comment: I see what I did wrong. I thought they were both the same thing.

Comment: understanding what you did wrong is important step to not make the same mistake again ^_^